# Firestore errors: Firestore (9.1.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I have two expo projects that need to connect to the same Firestore database, however in the first project it retrieves the data without a problem but in the second one it throws me this error:

```
@firebase/firestore:, Firestore (9.1.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
```

The connection code, imports and queries are the exact same (copy/paste), even the query is the same, as I was just testing.

The error message goes on telling me that it is usually a problem with the internet connection. I know that that's not the problem as well as my code, since it does run in the other project. What I want to know is if someone has run into or has any knowledge about these kind of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that installing firestore is not enough as the documentation states, you also have to install firebase, in my case, using

```
% yarn add firebase
```

or

```
% npm install firebase
```

Wasn't enough, I had to use specifically this version

```
% npm install firebase@9.6.11
```

Once done that, everything worked as expected.